# Installing Epson TM-U220 on Raspbian Jessie with Pixel

Tags: raspbian, printing, cups

I'm using Raspbian Jessie with PIXEl version March 2017, 2017-03-02, kernel 4.4.

I'm already installing CUPS and trying some methods.

The methods that I already try and still did not work :

> https://www.howtogeek.com/169679/how-to-add-a-printer-to-your-raspberry-pi-or-other-linux-computer/
>      Tried to set the printer as Epson 8pin. It works. But the autocutter and cashdrawer did not work.
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGOcgz6z81I (epsonsimplecups)
>     It prints an unknown text... but the cashdrawer function works

Downloaded **tmu-cups-1.0.0.0.tar.gz** Epson driver from epson-biz and did not work also...........

They can detect the printer, but still can not install the driver properly.

any idea how to make Epson TM-U220 work prooperly on raspbian (also need the cashdrawer and autocutter) ?

---

Tried PythonESCPOS from https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos

But when I tried :

> python setup.py build
>
> sudo python setup.py install

It can not works... give me error message...

Here's the error messages :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/escpos/python-escpos $ python setup.py build
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
  warnings.warn(msg)
your setuptools is too old (<12)
setuptools_scm functionality is degraded
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 138, in <module>
    'python-escpos = escpos.cli:main'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 266, in __init__
    _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 301, in finalize_options
    ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools_scm/integration.py", line 19, in version_keyword
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools_scm/__init__.py", line 123, in get_version
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools_scm/version.py", line 133, in format_version
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools_scm/version.py", line 105, in guess_next_dev_version
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools_scm/version.py", line 97, in guess_next_version
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'




same error on : sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/63384/edit) your question. What do you mean by "It did not work"?. Can you please tell us what you did and post the error messages you received?

Comment: Does it need to work as a CUPS printer? If not, maybe [python-escpos](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos) as discussed [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?&t=19883) might help you.

Comment: First I Install cups n tried howtogeek method. But still the Epson TM-U220 did not show up. I tried with Epson 8pin it can print. But the autocutter and cashdrawer did not work...

Then I tried the youtube method. Also did not work either...

Comment: let me try the python-escpos :)

Comment: I tried : 

python setup.py build  /// sudo python setup.py install

and can not works... give me error message...

Comment: can not building the installer

Comment: Please, don't post this as comments. This is hard to read and really tiresome. Instead [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/63384/edit) your question and add the information there,

Comment: Can please you edit your question and add output containing the error?

Comment: OK, I already edit my question :)

Comment: Please edit the question and add the error messages. I can't help you without those.

Comment: how about this ?

Comment: `your setuptools is too old (<12)` is your current problem. To resolve this, follow the instructions of this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/683730/75166

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the "TM Series Printer Driver for Linux Version 3.0.0 (for Impact Receipt: TM-U220)" from the "TM Series Printer Driver for Linux" here:

https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=6408&scat=32&pcat=3

Then untarred tmx-cups-src.tar

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake
sudo ./build.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

Choose the "EPSON TM Impact Receipt (en, en) " when installing.

I used default option of Media Size "Roll paper 76 x 200 mm" and "Paper Reduction" as "None" and "Buzzer/ Cash Drawer" as "Not used" and "Paper Cut" as "No cut"